# JavaScript Get <Textarea> to send the Enter Key Strokes instead of spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a forum type of website, and I am having problems formatting the

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="16" id="Description" type="text" name="message" placeholder="message"></textarea>
```

If I were to type enter or multiple spaces it would just format it back into single spaces. I am sending this data to my Node Server, and saving the body into the database. I want to store a version of this data in a way so I can see where the enter / multiple spaces are so when I paste the text in the post, I will get the enter's and space's

Comment: This seems more of Server-side script related issue...Just test the value which is being sent over server..

Comment: Oh your right, the enters get sent correctly when I log it on my server.

Comment: Then tag it as `nodejs` question and add your server-side logic..